# Changing the colour of every 5th div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a lot of divs after each other, 4 in each row.
I'm using the nth-child selector to change the padding of every 4th div.

Now I want to change the rollover property every 5th time.

something like this:

```
.content_tab_hover:nth-child(5n+1){
    background: #ce1c5e;
}
.content_tab_hover:nth-child(5n+2){
    background: #009acf;
}
.content_tab_hover:nth-child(5n+3){
    background: #fcc712;
}
.content_tab_hover:nth-child(5n+4){
    background: #742f68;
}
.content_tab_hover:nth-child(5n+5){
    background: #389a28;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/TuRzD/

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not targeting the correct DIV. It should be:

```
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+1) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #ce1c5e;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+2) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #009acf;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+3) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #fcc712;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+4) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #742f68;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+5) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #389a28;
}
```

`.content_tab_hover:nth-child(n)` selects the n-th `.content_tab_hover` element from each `.overlay` DIV.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the selector. The nth-child should be on `.content_tab:nth-child() .content_tab_hover` instead of `.content_tab_hover:nth-child()...`

Try this:

```
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+1) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #ce1c5e;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+2) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #009acf;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+3) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #fcc712;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+4) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #742f68;
}
.content_tab:nth-child(5n+5) .content_tab_hover{
    background: #389a28;
}
```

**Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TuRzD/6/**